# WP как вывести название категории, если она пустая

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Как в wordpress - вывести название категории, когда в категории нет записей.

я использую следующее :

```
<?php
$catid = the_category_id( $echo = false );
echo $catid;
```

и после я пытаюсь в  нужной области вывести само название:

```
<?php echo get_cat_name($catid);?>
```

Но название не появляется , потому что категория пустая, если я добавлю в нее хоть одну запись, то название категории покажется.

Как мне вывести название категории без записей?

WP ver= 5.5.1

Answer (score 0):

Куда проще чем казалось, абсолютно другой запрос :

```
<?php echo single_cat_title();?>
```